# error.length is throwing an error in HTML of LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

Hi I am trying to render a component on the basis of the length of the track property but it is throwing an error of  of not supporting. kindly help.
Below is the code :

```
<template if:true={error.length}>
                    <c-error-cmp error={error}></c-error-cmp>
            </template>
```

error i am getting :

```
Action.prototype.finishAction Error  [Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<template if:true={error.length}>
```

Should be:

```
<template if:true={error}>
```

If `error` is undefined/null, then the original code throws an exception when you try to access `error.length`. The latter checks if the variable itself is undefined/null before attempting to evaluate anything inside the template.